# R package development using UTF-8 on Windows

Tags: r, windows, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm in a non-English speaking country. We need to be able to develop using our local language in our code.

I'm trying to develop a package but running into encoding issues. The package is basically just a way for me to organize my code. This means it contains magic strings for column names and data values, for example:

```
data %>% select("Åsen", Region) %>% filter(Region == "Åholt")
```

This code, wrapped in a function defined in my package will fail with the `Å` being converted to some strange characters when I try to run it, causing it to fail as there is no column or data containing said strange characters.

All my source code files use UTF-8 encoding.

Developing in English is not an option.

I have the following set in my package DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends: R (>= 3.30)
Encoding: UTF-8
```

**Edit:**

Using `options(encoding = "UTF-8")` at the top of my main script from which I call my package seems to fix the issue with having non-ascii characters in my package code.

Can anyone who knows more about that shed some light on this?

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()` report?

Comment: Lots of packages and locale of Danish_Denmark.1252. But i just tried to set option(encoding = "UTF-8") and thats seems to make it work. Apparently magic strings, even ones written in a UTF8 encoded file are translated to latin1/cp1252. Like Encoding("Åsen") returns Latin1

Comment: What I do is keep my locale (French), but convert strings to UTF8 when creating data or using those in code.

Comment: I'm also using PoEdit to create the translated strings in French using gettext and sprintf.

Comment: @Cedric Im not sure if that really is a solution. Isn't it annoying having to wrap every string in enc2utf8 or similar?

Comment: As you do I'm keeping all my source files for the package in "UTF8". But for those strings I would load them first and convert them to "UTF8". The stringi package is now handy to do that.

Comment: Oh but that's what I had to do. And yes it's a pain. as you can see in one of [my files](https://github.com/cran/stacomiR/blob/master/R/interface_report_dc.R) I'm using gettext everywhere. The advantage is that I can then translate everything nicely with poedit. It's working very well.

Comment: But perhaps there is a better solution. I've marked your question as a favorite and see what comes.

Answer (score 0):

My random notes on R with UTF-8, especially when used with MySQL/MariaDB:

R / RStudio

```
Tool -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SET NAMES utf8')
```

Rails: [Rails and utf8mb4](https://blog.arkency.com/2015/05/how-to-store-emoji-in-a-rails-app-with-a-mysql-database/)

Ruby on Rails:

```
"\xD0\x9A\xD0\xB0\xD1\x81\xD0\xBB".force_encoding("UTF-8") => "Щасл"
```

Watch out for `rake db:reset` . Consider, instead, `rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate` . The reset just created the tables from the already stored schema which had the wrong charset and collation. But re-creating them from the migrations created them with the new charset and collation.

RoR: application_controller.rb

```
  def configure_charsets
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    suppress(ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET NAMES UTF8'
    end
  end
```

Edit your database.yml with below code line encoding: utf8

Answer (score 0):

I spent lot of time with that.

I use for Linux that a the top

```
options(encoding = "UTF-8")
```

and `iconv()` 
for database (SQL server) in my case:

```
sqlQuery(connexion_bdd,
    iconv(        
     "select * from mytable " ,
     "UTF-8","ISO88591")  , 
      stringsAsFactors=FALSE     
)
```

and also "Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8".

For ms Windows you could replace in my sentences `UTF-8` by `windows-1252`  if you don't want change the  default code page in your IDE. (1252 is the code page for Latin Alphabet in my ms Windows)